# Objective C: Access of primitive data type

Tags: objective-c

I want to access primitive data types like int, Bool in Objective C.
I have created one class in which I declared an integer varriable.
Now in other class i want to access this data and also set the value of it.

As in Objective C setter methods are applicable only for objects and I can't convert int to object.

So how would I be able to access the data ?

Please suggest some approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As in Objective C setter methods are applicable only for objects and I can't convert int to object.

Where did you get that idea.  You can have Objective-C properties that are primitive types using either properties or normal accessors.

```
// in the .h file
// intIVar and otherIntIvar are int instance variables

@property (assign) int myIntIVar;
//         ^^^^^^ stops the runtime from sending retain or copy to synth'd ivars
-(int) myOtherIntIVar;
-(void) setMyOtherIntIVar;

// in the .m file

@synthesize myIntIVar = intIVar;

-(int) myOtherIntIVar
{
    return otherIntIVar;
}

-(void) setMyOtherIntIvar: (int) newValue
{
    otherIntIvar = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use getters and setters with primitives.

Just use @synthesize, or create your own methods:

```
- (int)primitiveIvar;
- (void)setPrimitiveIvar:(int)_ivar;
```

Answer (score 0):

**chpwn** is correct and answers your question directly. This is just additional info.

If you want to convert a primitive value to an object, like for use in an **NSArray**, you wrap it in an **NSNumber** like this:

```
NSNumber *someValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 5];
```

The same thing applies to *float*, *BOOL*, *char*, *double* and a ton of other primitive types.

To put the object value back into a primitive:

```
int someInteger = [someValue intValue];
```

***Rule of thumb:***

If you're doing lots of math operations, need a number for local use, or need high performance, use primitives.

If you're storing values in the collection classes (**NSArray**, **NSSet**, **NSDictionary** etc…) and need object-like behaviors such as membership tests, predicate filtering, easy saving to disk or plist creation, use **NSNumber**.

Have a look at the *NSNumber class documentation* for more info.